# CasperJS doesn't follow link on an ASP site

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to mimic browser behavior on a site built with ASP, which seems to use a lot of javascript based links and UI using CasperJS. I'm pretty stuck, and not sure how what to do next.

I'm using:`casperjs1.1.0-beta3`,`phantomjs1.9.8`, and the site url is https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx

This is the HTML link I want to click on:

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_ba040fcb_44f7_44fa_92d0_d088c5679794$ctl00$gvCasedetails','Page$3')">3</a>
</td>
```

The site has some SSL configuration problems, so CasperJS is run with some additional flags to work: `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 icsid.js`

`icsid.js` just tries to open the site and click on a link to get to the next page of results. I want to check all results.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["./jquery.min.js"],
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36',
    }
});

casper.start('https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx', function(){});

casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(5000);
    this.capture('screenshot0.png');
    casper.then(function(){
        var text = this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery('.gdcol a')[0].text;
        });
        console.log('text: ' + text);

        this.evaluate(function(){
            // try to go to second page
            return jQuery('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "2"; })[0].click();
        });
    });


    casper.then(function(){
        this.wait(5000);

        var size = this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery('.gdcol a').size();
        });
        console.log('size: ' + size);

        // if successfully clicked and changed url, the link text will change
        var text = this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery('.gdcol a')[0].text;
        });
        console.log('text: ' + text);

        // if it's still on the first page, this will be null
        var page = this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "1"; })[0].text;
        });
        console.log('page: ' + page);

        // if it's on the second page, this will be null
        var page = this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "2"; })[0].text;
        });
        console.log('page: ' + page);

        this.capture('screenshot1.png');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

This is the resulting log:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx"
2015-07-23 11:48:31.255 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.256 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSuboptimalRequest to debug.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.278 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.279 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.280 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.280 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.479 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2015-07-23 11:48:31.480 phantomjs[10699:d13] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected ./jquery.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3 https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 1886ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /Users/yubrew/app/lib/tasks/screenshot0.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /Users/yubrew/app/lib/tasks/screenshot0.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 2347ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 4/6 https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 4/6: done in 2351ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 5000ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/6 https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
text: ARB/15/30
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/6: done in 7377ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/6 https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
size: 50
text: ARB/15/30
page: null
page: 2
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /Users/yubrew/app/lib/tasks/screenshot1.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /Users/yubrew/app/lib/tasks/screenshot1.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/6: done in 7491ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/7 https://icsid.worldbank.org/apps/ICSIDWEB/cases/Pages/AdvancedSearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/7: done in 7493ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 5000ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 7 steps in 12493ms
```

Note that the screenshots and console log indicate that the page contents has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Element.click(), because it doesn't do anything in PhantomJS most of the time. Use CasperJS' `click()` function that tries many thing to properly click an element.

Since CSS selectors don't support matches based on text, you can use XPath to solve this:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
...
casper.click(x("//a[text()='2']"));
```

---

Your other misconception is that `casper.wait()` actually does something. All `then*()` and `wait*()` functions are asynchronous step functions. When you call them, you're only scheduling a step that should be executed at the end of the current step.

For example, if you call this:

```
this.wait(5000);
this.capture('screenshot0.png');
this.then(function(){...
```

it is executed like this:

```
this.capture('screenshot0.png');
this.wait(5000);
this.then(function(){...
```

If you can, you should wrap synchronous function calls in a `casper.then()`.